# Touch Creates File with Different Owner

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I'm connecting to my Raspberry Pi using SSH as user mike.  I use touch to create a file in a directory whose owner pi / users.  Both mike and pi are in group users.  The newly created file has owner pi / users.  I would think it would be mike / users.

```
$ ls -l ..
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 1 pi users 4096 Feb 12 15:03 parent_dir
$ touch z
$ ls -l z                                             
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pi users 0 Feb 12 15:03 z
```

Is this expected behavior? Why isn't the owner mike / users?

Comment: Are you the user mike on the Raspberry? What does the `whoami` command report?

Comment: Yes, I'm user mike.  `whoami` reports `mike`.